# How to deal with this Generic list conversion from Java to Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, list, generics, kotlin

In the process of rewriting Java code to Kotlin I need to define the object type of a list. The thing is that it **is** unknown and it can contain different type of objects. The situation:

In my Java class I have defined a list with `TopicNode` objects: `private List<TopicNode> nodes`. Those objects can contain Messages of a type `T extends Message`. Messages can be of type `Boolean`, `Int32`, `String` etc. A node looks like:

> TopicNode.java

```
class TopicNode<T extends Message> extends AbstractNodeMain {
    // Implementation
}
```

The Javaclass containing this list looks like:

> TopicControllerImpl.java

```
public class TopicControllerImpl implements TopicController {

    private List<TopicNode> nodes;

    @Override
    public void subscribe(String topic, Class type, Messenger subscriber) {
        TopicNode node = findOrCreateNode(topic, type);
        node.addListener(subscriber);
    }

    private <T extends Message> TopicNode<T> findNode(String topic) {
        for (TopicNode node : nodes) {
            if (node.getTopic().equals(topic)) {
                return (TopicNode<T>) node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private <T extends Message> TopicNode findOrCreateNode(String topic, Class<T> type) {
        TopicNode<T> node = findNode(topic);
        if (node != null) {
            return node;
        }
        // If node doesn't exist yet, create it, run it and add it to the collection
        node = new TopicNode<>(topic, type);
        executor.execute(node, configuration);
        nodes.add(node);
        return node;
    }
}
```

When I try to define the list like this in Kotlin  (`private val nodes: ArrayList<TopicNode> = ArrayList()`), the compiler says: `One type argument expected for class TopicNode<T : Message>`.

To solve this you can define the class and list like the following in Kotlin:

> TopicControllerImpl.kt

```
class TopicControllerImpl<T : Message>(/** args */) : TopicController<T> {
    private val nodes: ArrayList<TopicNode<T>> = ArrayList()

    override fun subscribe(topic: String, type: Class<T>, subscriber: Messenger) {
        val node = findOrCreateNode(topic, type)
        node.addListener(subscriber)
    }

    private fun findNode(topic: String): TopicNode<T>? {
        return nodes.firstOrNull { it.topic == topic }
    }

    private fun findOrCreateNode(topic: String, type: Class<T>): TopicNode<T> 
    {
        var node = findNode(topic)
        if (node != null) {
            return node
        }
        // If node doesn't exist yet, create it, run it and add it to the collection
        node = TopicNode(topic, type)
        executor.execute(node, configuration)
        nodes.add(node)

        return node
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that you need to define the type of `T` that is used for the list in `TopicControllerImpl` while this unknown and it is not required in Java. It is unknown what the type of `Message` is going to be and it can also vary.

Since this is the case, how can I deal with this situation in Kotlin? Is it even possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You should never use raw types in Java in the first place, see [wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) or [their Kotlin equivalent](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections).

Comment: @Klyner, I tried converting your code to kotlin. Is [this](https://pastebin.com/MuRMFRCe) ok with your requirement ?

Comment: @theapache64 The problem this solution gives me is that when you want to define `TopicControllerImpl` you need to specify `T`. `T` is variable in the list of Topic Nodes in Java but Kotlin wants us to specify it.

Comment: @Klyner did you solve the problem? If possible I would like to know what did you do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`You should never use raw types in Java in the first place, see wildcards or their Kotlin equivalent - @Moira`

I solved this problem by avoiding the use of the raw type `T`. So I removed the `<T : Message>` in the class definition; meaning that wherever `T` is used, the object filling this up need to extend from `Message`.

Let's say we have an object `Monkey` which is a subclass of abstract class `Animal`.

In kotlin, in contrast to Java, it is possible to add a list of Monkeys to a List that requires Animals. So:

```
List<Monkey> monkeys = getMonkeys()
List<Animal> animals = monkeys      // Will compile with Kotlin; will not compile for Java
```

This ability to do this is caused by so called `covariance`.

More information about generics and variance: https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47

It states that it is not possible to assign monkeys to the list of animals because:

> This is because generics in Java ignore type vs subtype relation between its components. In the case when List cannot be assigned to List nor vice versa, this is called invariance. There is no subtype to supertype relationship here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a difference between generic and wildcard. For example

```
private val nodes: ArrayList<TopicNode<T>> = ArrayList()
```

means I will have an array of this generic class with the **given** type `T`. while

```
private val nodes: ArrayList<TopicNode<*>> = ArrayList()
```

means I will have an array of this generic class with **mixed** type.

If you want to use the first one change your **class** definition but if you want the second one change your **array** declaration.

Comment: How and why should I change my array definition?

Comment: I explained the differences between two, it's up to you to choose the one that serves you best. now about how just add type whenever you defining or declaring or passing the array..

Comment: As you see in my example code `TopicControllerImpl.kt` I already used the generic raw type solution. But this leads to the issue that TopicControllerImpl needs to be defined with a specified object `T`. In Java this could be avoided but in Kotlin it seems that it cannot be avoided.

Comment: You had to specify the generic raw type for class because you are using a typed generic. As with the second solution you can go ahead and define it as wildcard so you don't have to specify the class type anymore.

Comment: @Klyner btw I mixed the array and class definition so I updated my answer, sorry for confusion.
If you want raw type change your class definition as you did. If you want mixed type change your array definition.